# How to invite friends individually for Dragon City?

Tags: facebook, dragon-city

So I've noticed that when I click this [button](http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/7831/xjw7.jpg), every single friend is actually checked. What if I don't want to invite everybody to play this game? What if I want to just invite 1 person? Is there an option for that? I don't want to manually uncheck all 300 of my friends.

As you notice in this image, the black censor is the friend's profile icon and the muddy censor is the friend's name. Of course you see every name being checked. Now there are arrows to navigate multiple pages to uncheck.

What if I only want to invite just one person?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Click the words Select none where I have circled in yellow then find the friend you want and check their box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click unselect on the top left hand side of your friends list